# temp name in list-comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I've been messing around a bit with python list comprehensions and created this one-liner to compute the max even number that is made as the product of two three-digit numbers:

```
max([ i*j for i in range(100,1000) for i in range(100,1000) if i*j%2== 0 ])
```

The question is the following: is there a way to avoid re-computing the value of i*j like assigning a temporary name for it and using it?

The whole thing that's buzzing me is that I compute the value of `i*j` twice and if I wanted one more if function, I'd need one more. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: You can also make it more memory efficient by dropping the `[` `]` brackets, so the max function consumes values as they are generated, rather than the list consuming them all, then the max function consuming from the list that is taking up memory.

Answer (score 3):

If `i*j` is expensive, use a generator function:

```
def values():
    for i in range(100, 1000):
        for j in range(100, 1000):
            ij = i * j
            if ij % 2 == 0:
                yield ij

max(values())
```

Resist the temptation to nest generator expressions here; yes, it can be done but only serves to make your code undecipherable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how the interpreter deals with your code.

But you could use:

```
max((u for u in (i*j for i in range(100,1000) for j in range(100,1000)) if u%2== 0))
```

And in this case I think it better to use the generator () instead of using a list [], because you don't need the all the data, just the max one.

Comment: well yes but my question is actually if its possible to use a temporary name . the example code is just for pointing out a possible use case. so the question remains...

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it is very much within Python's philosophy to say: If you want to re-use some intermediate result, then give it a name. Idiomatically,  `_` is used to  suggest a temporary name. Also, if a list comprehension or generator expression spans two or more lines, it is probably best to re-write it with explicit for-loops anyway.

That said, one may (mis-) use Python's functional capabilities to write your code without *any* intermediate names. Almost, that is: Because we can't use `functools.partial` to fixate non-leftmost and non-keyword arguments, we have to construct a `mod2` functions ourselves instead of using `partial`.

```
from itertools import iterfalse, product, starmap
from operator import mod, mul
mod2 = lambda x: mod(x, 2) # this would be nicer with functools.partial
max(filterfalse(mod2, starmap(mul, product(range(100, 1000), repeat=2))))
```

However, while I do believe the above code answers your question, I don't think this solution is intuitively understandable – just give your intermediate result a name.